# Shell Script Compares: Why double-quotes around variables?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I shell scripts I see compares always written this way:

```
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]
then ...
```

**What the purpose of the double-quotes around the variable?**

If I remove the quotes then it doesn't seem to have an effect. Is it for preventing something?

Comment: And there's a **comprehensive** post on [unix.se] about [the security aspect of quoting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells).

Comment: In this case, `$?` always returs a number which signifies exit status of previous command(s). So quoting or not quoting is irrelevant for this one, but quoting exists to avoid word splitting, aka treating items separately. With variable `v='hello world'` , when you use bare `$v` shell will treat its expansion as two elements `hello` and `world`, with quotes - `"$v"` is treated as single unit. Read the linked posts, it's explained much more in-depth there.

Comment: Also don't be confused by the "word" in word splitting, has nothing to do with text. It applies just as equally to `v='1234 5678'`

Comment: @Sergiy Kolodyazhnyy Thanks a lot.  :)  The quotes make now sense to me.